# mysql_real_escape_string with variables extracted from an array

Tags: mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

original post:

My script is not working (it's not recording the data).  It was working before I added the mysql_real_escape_string, so I'm wondering if maybe I have not implemented it correctly:

```
$array = json_decode($downstream,TRUE);
$name = $array["status"]["name"];
$title = $array["status"]["title"];
$table = "mrTable";
$insert = "INSERT INTO $table (name, title) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."')";
```

Does that implementation at INSERT look correct to you?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the entire code, hopefully this will help.  It is still not working though.  When the real_escape_string function is used, NONE of the data elements get recorded in the database.  As soon as I remove the escape function, data is written fine (unless of course an apostrophe shows up).

Here we go:

```
//read contents of this file:

$json_data = file_get_contents('../list.txt');

//json to a php array

$array = json_decode($json_data,TRUE));

//store in mysql table

$table = "table1";
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($array["current"]["name"]);
$code = mysql_real_escape_string($array["current"]["code"]);

$insert="INSERT INTO $table (name, code) VALUES ('$name', '$code')";

$con = mysql_connect($db, $user, $pass);
if (!$con)
    {
    die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    };

mysql_select_db($yup, $con);

mysql_query($insert) OR die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($con);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Fixed!  You need to connect to the database before first mentioning mysql_real_escape_string.  Everything is working now...no blank data.

Comment: i don't see any variable $name. You should put $artist instead.

Comment: And did you check for errors after execution? The output of `mysql_error()`?

Comment: Eugene - that was my error while transcribing the code for this post.  variable names are consistent in the actual script.

Comment: Add an `or die(mysql_error())` to the query line. If m_r_e_s is mangling the query somehow to introduce a syntax error, the mysql_error will tell you what went wrong. However, I can't see how it would.

Comment: Thanks, that was there, I'd only included partial code.  I've edited my post to contain the whole script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be connected to a database to use mysql_real_escape_string. You don't seem to be. Make sure mysql_connect is over your line where you define `$insert`

Comment: you also need to be connected to do mysql_query(), and the OP said this was working before m_r_e_s was added to the mix, implying that he IS connected, e.g... the connection is simply not shown.

Comment: Well, many times people say they only do one certain change and it turns out they did something else that they didn't knew mattered. Because just adding mysql_real_escape_String() obviously should not cause any problems, he has to do something else wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  I am connected, and the only thing I changed here was that I added the mysql_real_escape_string stuff.

Comment: You should show your whole code then. And as Marc said, add or die(mysql_error()) after all your mysql_* to debug.

Comment: I've updated my post to show the current code, entirely.  Thank you.

Comment: With that code the problem is exactly what I've already told you... You need to have an active database connection to run mysql_real_escape_string(), add or die(mysql_error()) and It's exactly what the error would say. PHP like any other language reads from top to bottom which means you need mysql_connect over the escaping part.

Answer (score 0):

Never insert values directly into a query string! Even if they are escaped, it's not a smart idea. Instead, use parametrised statements as such, which will render attacks like ' OR 1 = 1-- useless. You don't need to escape values for parametrised statements either...

```
PREPARE statement FROM
'INSERT INTO table (col1, col2)
 VALUES
 (?, ?)'

EXECUTE statement USING ('val1', 'val2')

DEALLOCATE statement
```

Deallocate only when you're done. You can re-execute as many times as you'd like with different values. If you are going to re-execute anyways, there is a gain in performance as well from doing it this way! (Because the statement is only prepared once for an infinite number of executions.) I advise you to implement this method and then come back if you are still having problems.

Comment: Thanks Mr_Creosote, I'll check it out.  Still curious why my current approach is not working though...

Comment: My thought was that perhaps the escaping was causing problems because you mentioned that it stopped working after you implemented the escape function. Busy at the moment but I can take a look at this later on if you are still encountering problems.

Answer (score -1):

Please don't try to escape your parameters.  Use bind variables.  See http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for examples.